# Mover underline en medio de la palabra

Tags: css, css3

Actualmente tengo 2 underline que los quiero unir en medio de la palabra

como mover el underline en medio de la palabra? cuando lo intento se baja + la palabra

```css
.err {
  border-top: 2px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.err:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 5px;
  left: -2px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>hola
  <div class="err">mundo</div> informatico</div>
```

El underline deberia simular una linea de Error, pero en el medio de la palabra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el underline situado arriba que simula ser una linea de ERROR, pero quiero centrarlo al medio

```css
.err {
  border-top: 2px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.err:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -2px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>hola
  <div class="err">mundo</div> informatico</div>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que las líneas rojas engloben la palabra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No añadas la segunda línea de "error" en el elemento, sino en otro pseudo elemento, así:

```css
.err {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.err:after,
.err:before{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.err:before{
  left: 2px;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<div>hola
  <div class="err">mundo</div> informatico</div>
```

Para situarlo al medio, asigna el `top` al 50% de la palabra y subelo un poco con `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

Para la segunda línea posicionarlo como quieras usando `calc` y `left`, ejemplo:

```
top: calc(50% - 1px);
left: 2px;
```

¿Era esto lo que necesitaba?
Coloque la palabra en opacidad baja, para que hiciera mejor contraste, con el negro, casi no se ve bien las lineas rojas.

Comment: si el resultado es el esperado, me explicas porque usar los pseudos .err:after, .err:before{ juntos?

Comment: Porque 1) usas la primera línea punteada en uno de los bordes de la palabra, esto te deja solo con la opción de posicionarla arriba, abajo, a la izquierda y a la derecha de la palabra, pero no más. 2) Con los dos pseudoelementos, puedes acomodar las líneas punteadas en la posición que quieras, al medio, diagonal, de forma independiente etc.

Answer (score 1):

Así como estás utilizando el pseudoelemento after, puedes usar el pseudoelemento before, incluso podrías usar calc() para darle una ubicación más adecuada según lo que quieras lograr.

```css
.err {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.err::before,
.err::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 53%;
  left: -2px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
}

.err::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 47%;
}
```

```html
<div>hola
  <div class="err">mundo</div> informatico</div>
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta, fijate en la imagen

Comment: mmm ok, no es lo mismo que estaba planteado inicialmente.

Comment: una pregunta mas, .err::before,
.err::after { es necesario usarlos juntos?

Comment: No es necesario, simplemente es una forma de evitar duplicar código, básicamente estás aplicando el código común a los dos en esa declaración, y luego especifico lo que es distinto en ::before. A menos que no haya entendido tu pregunta.

Comment: tu respuesta esta muy bien, es el resultado que necesito, no se a cual poner como respuesta correcta

Comment: Lo determinas según la que consideres más útil, completa, y a veces cuando son iguales o muy similares, la persona que respondió primero.

Answer (score 1):

Sé que ya tienes soluciones usando pseudo-elementos, yo te voy a poner una solución sin necesidad de usarlos. Puedes decorar el texto directamente para que tenga una línea sobre el texto (con el valor "line-through" para [`text-decoration-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line)), y que esa línea sea ondulada (con el valor "wavy" para [`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style)).

Aquí lo puedes ver:

```css
.err {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>hola <div class="err">mundo</div> informatico</div>
```

Pero esta solución tiene un par de problemas (al menos de momento):

- No puedes controlar exactamente cómo se ve el ondulado (que lo controla el navegador)
- Su [soporte no está muy extendido](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-style) (p.e. no se verá bien en IE/Edge)

Comment: que interesante y con menos codigo